# Spring, how to decide on client which consumer should service use?

Tags: java, spring

Is there any possibility to call service method on server from client like:

```
someServiceHolder.getService(MyService.class).runMethodOnServerWithConsumer("myConsumerService#consumerA")
```

the method then:

```
public void runMethodOnServerWithConsumer(String consumerMethodName) {
 Consumer<Object> consumerA = somehowGetConsumerInstance(consumerMethodName);
  consumerA.accept(doSomething());
}
```

It's maybe not related just to Spring. Maybe more generally, how to work around the impossibility of serializing methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use RMI (Remote Method Invocation).
Java Remote Method Invocation allows invoking an object residing in a different Java Virtual Machine. Spring Remoting allows to leverage RMI in an easier and cleaner way.

You need to have following code on the server

```
@Bean
public RmiServiceExporter exporter(MyService implementation) {
    Class<MyService> serviceInterface = MyService.class;
    RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
    exporter.setServiceInterface(serviceInterface);
    exporter.setService(implementation);
    exporter.setServiceName(serviceInterface.getSimpleName());
    exporter.setRegistryPort(1099); 
    return exporter;
}
```

Then you should add following code to your client:

```
@Bean
public RmiProxyFactoryBean service() {
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactory = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
    rmiProxyFactory.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:1099/MyService");
    rmiProxyFactory.setServiceInterface(MyService.class);
    return rmiProxyFactory;
}
```

After that, you can call methods that you need on client application:

```
SpringApplication.run(App.class, args).getBean(MyService.class);
service.method("test");
```

You can find more details on https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html